# How can I transform a numpy array of labels to an array of colors, from correspondance given by third array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need help to find an efficient method (as fast as possible) to transform a numpy array of labels into a numpy array of colors.

Let's take a simple exemple:

- A contains labels (ints):

  ```
  A = [0,45,45,22,0,45,45,22]
  ```
- B contains all the labels:

  ```
  B = np.unique(A) = [0,45,22]
  ```
- C contains RGB values:

  ```
  C = [[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]]
  ```

and the ith element of `C` is the color of the ith label in `B`. For example, color of label `45` is `[0,1,0]`.

According to this, A should be transform to:

```
[[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1], ...]
```

I already tried the following piece of code, but it is very slow:

```
result = np.array([C[np.where(B==x)[0][0]] for x in A])
```

Does someone knows a more efficient solution ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.unique`'s inverse index for that:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0,45,45,22,0,45,45,22])
C = np.array([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]])
_, inverse_idx = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)

result = C[inverse_idx]
# array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
```

**Important note**: `np.unique` returns values and indices as a **sorted** array, so `np.unique(A)` gives `[0, 22, 35]`, and not `[0, 45, 22]`. If you do want to have it in the order in which they appear, it will require an additional operation using the original index of the values of A:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0,45,45,22,0,45,45,22])
C = np.array([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]])
_, idx, inverse_idx = np.unique(A, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

result = C[idx.argsort()[inverse_idx]]
# array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Great!! I didn't know about inverse index. I tested it and I save a lot of time. I'll use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = np.array([0,45,45,22,0,45,45,22])
B = np.unique(A)
C = np.array([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]])


from numba import njit

@njit
def f(arr, labels, colors):
    result = np.zeros((len(arr), 3))
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        result[arr==label] = colors[i]
    return result
```

compile the function using a single element from `A`:

```
f(A[:1], B, C)
```

Now:

```
result = f(A, B, C)
```

It requires `9.5367431640625e-05` sec on my machine, vs `3.123283e-04` sec of  your solution

I also tried my funtion on an 1'000'000 numbers `A` and it required `0.0359194278717041` vs `5.217064619064331` sec of your solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it sounds great! However, I prefer not to use an additional library, I'll use the solution from @ye olde noobe.